# Is there a way to block MacOS terminal resize sys calls

Tags: c++, macos, unix, terminal, console

Is there a way I can block and unblock the system calls that are called when resizing the the MacOS terminal in C++ as it can mess up cin aswell as the read() function?
The issue/feature of resizing a terminal window causing inputs/errors doesn't seem to be a thing when resizing terminals in most Linux distributions.

I have tried blocking all system calls:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct termios old = {0};
sigset_t mask, oldmask;

sigfillset(&mask);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
```

however this causes side affects of CTRL+C not working properly when trying to exit the program.

Comment: If MacOS is like Linux, then what's probably happening here is that you only need to block the `SIGWINCH` signal. Leave the rest of the signals alone.

Comment: FYI, your example code is not blocking syscalls -- it is blocking signals. Your question is very confusing but I suspect what you want to do is ignore the SIGWINCH signal.

Comment: Resizing the terminal window does **not** feed anything into your stdin, so I don't know what you are talking about here. Actually I don't think that this would be technically possible for a terminal application. Please post a minimum C++ program, which demonstrates the behaviour, and tell us which terminal you are using.